# Gradle dependency for compile time only and test

Tags: gradle

I am basically looking for a way to mimic the maven dependency `provided`. I am building a jar (an extension to a db driver), which depends on another jar (the db driver), but I do not want to include that jar.

I am able to use `compileOnly` to achieve that, however now the tests won't run or compile as the required jar is not included in tests.

I tried through the list of available dependencies like `testCompile`, however I could not find one that makes the jar available at compile time and when the tests run and compile.

How would I include that jar properly?

**Edit:** As requested, the build.gradle file:

```
group 'com.mygroup'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compileOnly "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.3.0"
    testCompile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.3.0"
}
```

Listing the dependency twice does work, however obviously is not a very nice solution

Comment: did you list the dependency as both `compileOnly` and `testCompile`?  Also please show your `build.gradle` file

Comment: listing the dependency twice does work, however seems like a rather ugly workaround. I have added the `build.gradle` file to the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can extend your `testCompile` configuration from the `compileOnly` configuration:

```
configurations {
    testCompile.extendsFrom compileOnly
}
```

Comment: How can this be formulated in the Kotlin DSL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62452133/gradle-kotlin-dsl-extendsfrom

Comment: This is deprecated, planned for removal in Gradle 6.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783546/for-a-unit-test-that-has-a-compileonly-dependency-how-can-i-avoid-redeclaring-t

Answer (score 2):

I use the following;

```
sourceSets {
    // Make the compileOnly dependencies available when compiling/running tests
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
}
```

which is a line longer than the answer from tynn, but makes the intent clearer IMHO,

Comment: it's not longer if, as is my case, you have 10 `compileOnly` dependencies.  Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work for me.