# for a unit test that has a compileOnly dependency, how can i avoid redeclaring the dependency for availability at runtime?

Tags: testing, gradle, dependencies

I am currently using Gradle to build a project, and it has a dependency on a
third party component that I need at compile time, but which will be provided at runtime.
In maven I would declare this dependency as *provided*, and in Gradle I declare it as below:

```
  compileOnly group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.0.cloudera1'
```

The fact that I am depending on the above spark artifact is not really germane to the question (I provide this info to make the example more concrete.)

Now, suppose I want to write some unit tests for my app (or library as the case may be).
When using Gradle, the only way I figured out how to do this is clunky: I redeclare
the dependency as  a testCompile dependency, and my test is able to run:

```
  compileOnly group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.0.cloudera1'
  testCompile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.0.cloudera1'
```

I really don't like the repetition and clutter of declaring my dependency twice, and I'm wondering
if there is any better way to do this in Gradle ?

**Conclusion**

The answer from Mike put me on to the solution that I chose, which was to put this at the top level gradle file of my multi-project build.

```
subprojects {

  sourceSets {
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the answer provided by Mike is much more idiomatic and properly handles the differences between resolvable configurations and those that are not. `compileOnly` resolution, which will be triggered by your approach should emit a deprecation warning and become illegal in an upcoming Gradle version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a very standard way to declare Gradle dependencies. There are many cases in which `compileOnly` dependencies can be used, and not all of these require the dependency to be provided at runtime (unlike Maven's `provided` scope implies).

This is detailed further in Gradle's initial announcement for compile-only dependencies (https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies):

> Compile-only dependencies address a number of use cases, including:
>
> - Dependencies required at compile time but never required at runtime, such as source-only annotations or annotation processors;
> - Dependencies required at compile time but required at runtime only when using certain features, a.k.a. *optional dependencies*;
> - Dependencies whose *API* is required at compile time but whose *implementation* is to be provided by a consuming library, application or runtime environment.

What you have is the idiomatic way of declaring a compile-only dependency for your main sources which is also a runtime dependency for your test sources (although, technically, recent Gradle versions would suggest you replace the deprecated `testCompile` configuration with the `testImplementation` configuration).

However, one of the beautiful things about Gradle is that it is highly customizable. The built-in configurations, such as `compileOnly` and `testImplementation` can be modified. If you wish to change the built-in behavior, you can modify the `testImplementation` configuration to extend the `compileOnly` configuration, which will cause all `compileOnly` dependencies to be included when `testImplementation` is resolved:

```
// give test dependencies access to compileOnly dependencies to emulate providedCompile
configurations {
    testImplementation.extendsFrom compileOnly
}
```

Source: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/compileonly-dependencies-are-not-available-in-tests/15366/8

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin Gradle, to extend `testImplementation` from `compileOnly`:

```
configurations {
    configurations.testImplementation.get().apply {
        extendsFrom(configurations.compileOnly.get())
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).