# gradle kotlin DSL extendsfrom

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

How can I reformulate:

```
testCompile.extendsFrom compileOnly
```

of the Gradle Groovy DSL to its Kotlin-based equivalent?

```
configurations {
        testCompile{
            extendsFrom(compileOnly)
        }
    }
```

My approach above fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
configurations {
        create("testCompile").apply {
            extendsFrom(configurations.compileOnly.get())
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16251

Comment: Unresolved reference: compileOnly =(

Comment: great answer. worked perfectly on Android Studio Chipmunk with Gradle 7+

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change an already existing config use

```
configurations.testImplementation.get().extendsFrom(configurations.compileOnly.get())
```